# jquery the variable is not updated if I change the attribute

Tags: html, jquery

I have a problem with updating the call of the variable I created

I have a variable

```js
var idroom = $(".List-tab > .attiva").data("idroom");
```

this variable calls the id in this case is 6, if I click on another tab that variable will not change its value even though the 'attiva' class has been deleted

```html
<div class="List-tab">

<div class="nameroom attiva" data-namer="cupido" data-idroom="6"></div>
 <div class="nameroom" data-namer="cupido" data-idroom="8"></div>


</div>
```

the released value is 6
if I delete the active class, and place it on another div for example;

```html
<div class="nameroom attiva" data-namer="cupido" data-idroom="8"></div>
```

that variable does not update, and always remains at 6, why? if i move the attivaclass it should make me change the value, help

Comment: I don't know if I completely understood your question, a complete example would have been nice. Do you assume that the value of your variable `idroom` will be forever tied to the `data-idroom`-attribute of the div currently having class `attiva`? That's not the case. A variable will have the same value as long as you do not assign it a new value.
Maybe this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michivo/9sdwaezL/10/) helps explain.

Answer (score 0):

The content of a variable does NOT change when you assign new classes to an element. You have to set the variable idroom again after changing the classes.